# Jetpack Compose sheetContent is executed even though Bottom sheet is not expanded

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to make `sheetContent` execute only when the bottom sheet is expanded and decompose when you hide it.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. Here a workaround. For example, if you don't want to make unnecessary API requests when the bottom sheet is not expanded.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun RunWhenExpanded(sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (sheetState.currentValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) {
        content()
    } else {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(0.5.dp)) {}
    }
}
```

```
RunWhenExpanded(sheetState) {
    Content()
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way.